# Placing 3D Object automatically when app detects the plain

Tags: swift, uikit, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to create an ARKit app. The idea is when the app detects a flat surface it spawns a table and you can throw dices on it. First thing first, we need a table. But it only spawns when I add SCNNode and use `func touchesBegan`. Can someone propose a solution like I wanted initially?

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Tapped")
        
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: sceneView)           
        let results = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
            
        if let hitResults = results.first {                
            // Create a new scene
            let diceScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Table.scn")!
                
            if let diceNode = diceScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Table", recursively: true) {                  
                diceNode.position = SCNVector3(
                        x: hitResults.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
                        y: hitResults.worldTransform.columns.3.y,
                        z: hitResults.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
                    
                sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(diceNode)   
                print("Rendered")
            }
        }
    }
}
    
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            
    if anchor is ARPlaneAnchor {
            
        let planeAnchor = anchor as! ARPlaneAnchor
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))
         
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: planeAnchor.center.x, y: 0, z: planeAnchor.center.z)
        planeNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi/2, 1, 0, 0)
            
        let gridMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        gridMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/grid.png")
            
        plane.materials = [gridMaterial]  
        planeNode.geometry = plane               
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
            
    } else {
        return
    }   
}
```

I've tried to create only 3D model, but failed. The only thing I was able to do is to spawn model at the SCNPlane. Also the problem It spawns only at the top of the iPhone and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    print("plane detected")

    let planeAnchor = anchor
   // let planeNode = SCNNode()
    let x = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.x
    let y = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.y
    let z = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.z
   //planeNode!.position = SCNVector3(x: x, y: y, z: z)

   let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Table.scn")!
         let node = SCNNode()
         for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes{
             node.addChildNode(child)
         }
         node.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
         node.scale = SCNVector3(0.001,0.001,0.001)
         sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    
    print("Model placed")
}
```